# oracle apex 5 - how to reorder pages in menu

Tags: menu, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am dveloping an app in Oracle APEX 5. All of my pages have menu entry on the left-side menu, but the order of the pages in menu is different to the page numbers. Is there a way how to reorder pages in the menu?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your menu on the left is a standard APEX Universal Theme navigation menu, you do it like this:

1. Go to Shared Components
2. Click on Navigation Menu (under Navigation heading)
3. Click on the menu name

You should now see all the menu options for that menu, which have a sequence number.  Either edit the individual options or use Grid Edit and change the sequence numbers to give the order you want.